# Soundcloud API authentication without a web browser

Tags: soundcloud, xbmc

I am working on a Soundcloud XBMC add-on. The add-on is open source, and written in Python. I would like to allow users to login to their SoundCloud account via the add-on, however it's possible to have XBMC instances running in an environment without access to a typical web browser (e.g. [`raspbmc`](http://www.raspbmc.com/), which provides no window manager or graphical browser by default). Is there a way to still allow users to authenticate with this add-on without requiring use of the 'SoundCloud Connect Screen' and without violating the SoundCloud API TOS?

Answer (score 9):

This is not provided in theirs API, but after some digging into the libraries i figured it out. 
Make a POST to: `https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token`

with these params

`grant_type=password&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_SECRET_ID&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&scope=non-expiring`

this will return non expiring token that you can use for future authenticated requests.