# How to authentificate on SoundClound using OAuth 2.0 without using redirect uri on a desktop application?

Tags: authentication, soundcloud

I would like to develop a desktop application.
Sadly I got stuck at login. I want to use a web view which be SoundClound login end point.
https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=my_client_id&response_type=token_and_code&scope=non-expiring
Using the above I received error : "invalid_client: The configured redirect_uri of the client application is invalid."

Would be nice if API would tell you which parameters are required and which are optional. As I read about OAuth 2.0, redirect uri is optional. This caused me confusion when received this error. I also tried curl version, same kind of error.
If I tried to add a random redirect_uri won't pass either. (I'm aware this is about security.)

I found this answer, but I doesn't work and I think is error-prone: it requires 2 text fields and you're asking the user to provide their credentials (then you're able to do what you want with them...)
[Soundcloud API authentication without a web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449508/soundcloud-api-authentication-without-a-web-browser)

I would like to do the flow this way:

1. Open a web view with SoundCloud login end point.
2. User is providing his credentials to SoundCloud Server.
3. SoundCloud Server is sending me a token.

Something similar to OAuth 1.0.
Is possible or is there something similar to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 8):

After another few hours of research and keep trying to login I figured it out.
It works with redirect_uri after I did the setup for it on page "Your apps" on SoundCloud.